# Handling very large number in .net

Tags: c#, .net, types, fibonacci, largenumber

Is there any library to handle numbers bigger than that a `BigInteger` in .net can handle? Using `BigInteger` I could calculate the fibonacci series up to 3226th term. How to calculate more terms? Is there a way to join two `BigInteger` when an overflow occurs? Looking for your help.

Comment: I have been trying this.This is not to submit as homework anywhere.

Comment: What is it you are trying to accomplish? Just calculate fibonacci members of Satatic magnitudes or something else?

Comment: Also you can post a sample of your code which you are using to calculate the series.

Comment: @Venson: [The `homework` tag is deprecated.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147100/the-homework-tag-is-now-officially-deprecated) And AFAIK, a homework *flag* does not exist.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [BigInteger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger%28VS.100%29.aspx) to Handel an unknown large Number in .Net, there is no other way. If it Flows over, the Number is simply TO big to be handeld and there is no way see:

> Because the BigInteger type is immutable (see Mutability and the
>   BigInteger Structure) and because it has no upper or lower bounds, an
>   OutOfMemoryException can be thrown for any operation that causes a
>   BigInteger value to grow too large.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is yours, not of `BigInteger`:

```
BigInteger prev2 = 1;
BigInteger prev1 = 1;

int i = 3;

while (true)
{
    BigInteger fi = prev2 + prev1;
    Console.WriteLine("{0}th: {1}", i, fi);
    prev2 = prev1;
    prev1 = fi;
    i++;
}
```

it arrives at the 300000th without problems.